# Storing a wav file in an array

Tags: c#, wav, sample, naudio

I need a fast method to store all samples of a wav file in an array. I am currently working around this problem by playing the music and storing the values from the Sample Provider, but this is not very elegant.

From the NAudio Demo I have the Audioplayer Class with this Method:

```
   private ISampleProvider CreateInputStream(string fileName)
    {
        if (fileName.EndsWith(".wav"))
        {
            fileStream = OpenWavStream(fileName);
        }
          throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported extension");
        }
        var inputStream = new SampleChannel(fileStream, true);
        var sampleStream = new NotifyingSampleProvider(inputStream);
        SampleRate = sampleStream.WaveFormat.SampleRate;
        sampleStream.Sample += (s, e) => { aggregator.Add(e.Left); }; // at this point the aggregator gets the current sample value, while playing the wav file
        return sampleStream;
    }
```

I want to skip this progress of getting the sample values while playing the file, instead I want the values immediatly without waiting till the end of the file. Basically like the wavread command in matlab.

Comment: Because I want to make a STFT from a wav file and I want to calculate it by a button click. For that purpose I need all sample values..
I will try to add some Code and edit my first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AudioFileReader` to read the file. This will automatically convert to IEEE float samples. Then repeatedly call the `Read` method to read a block of samples into a float[] array.

Comment: Its working with AudioFileReader.ReadAsync() and a byte array, but I have trouble doing it right with AudioFileReader.Read() and a float array. I always end up with an index out of range exception. I.e I want to store the first 1024 float values in the float array samples: 
 SampleReader.Read(samples, 0, 1024); 
The next step would be:
 SampleReader.Read(samples, 1024, 2048);
but this step alway crashes..

Comment: usually you keep calling with (samples, 0, 1024).

Comment: @MiguelRodriguez do you found a solution?